# Why pipe to %{0} in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

PowerShell scripts sometimes pipe to %{0}:

```
[byte[]]$bytes = 0..65535 | %{0};
```

I know % is an alias for ForEach-Object and $_ represents the current pipeline object.

Is this solely to avoid output? Isn’t there a smarter way of doing it?

Comment: It is to produce zeros. `$bytes = [bytes[]]::new(65536)`

Answer (score 2):

The pipeline on the right-hand side simply outputs the integer `0` 65536 times - which when cast to `byte[]` produces a byte array of length 65536 with all values initialized to `0`.

You could also have done:

```
[byte[]]$bytes = ,0 * 65536
```

---

As [PetSerAl hints at](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51007711/why-pipe-to-0-in-powershell/51008844#comment89009053_51007711), this is unnecessary since arrays of numerical value types initialize all items to `0` anyways, meaning that simply creating a new array, like so:

```
# using the new constructor keyword, PowerShell version > 5, 
[byte[]]$bytes = [byte[]]::new(65536)
# using New-Object, PowerShell version > 2
[byte[]]$bytes = New-Object 'byte[]' 65536
```

would also have given you the exact same result

Comment: What made me confused was that I thought the overall left-hand side was piped, I.e. “[byte[]]$bytes = 0..65535”. Wouldn’t it be more correct to put parentheses around “0..65535 | %{0}”?

Comment: Assignment operators have lowest order of precedence in PowerShell, so the entire right-hand side expression is evaluated before assignment - with or without parentheses, it simply would not have any effect

Comment: I wouldn't go that far. It always seems to have the effect of making my eyes bleed ... ;)